# could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Unknown host

Tags: python, django

Setting up a Django project but I am getting a warning about setting up `postgres` as shown in the title, but I am unsure what this means.

**Full warning message:**

```
RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Unknown host
```

**And here is how I define `postgres` in my `settings.py`:**

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
    "NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME", "dbname"),
    "USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER", "dbuser"),
    "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD", "dbpassword"),
    "HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST", "postgres"),
    "PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT", "5432"),
}
```

}

Would it possible for someone to walk me through what is going wrong here? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use django with postgresql you need a reachable postgresql server.

You can install and run it locally : https://www.postgresql.org/download/

Then you postgresql server will be reachable on your localhost interface.
This DB_HOST config variable represent the address where your django server should contact your postgresql server.

So you can change the default value of your DB_HOST environment variable from "postgres" to "localhost", or directly set it into your environment ([using a .env file for example](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

Comment: Ah....I was used to using Docker just having the postgres image ready to go that I completely forgot if I wasn't using it I needed to install it locally. Appreciate the answer!

Comment: You are welcome. If your postgresql server is running inside a docker container you will need to use the container ip address or host name instead of "localhost"