# Can't Migrate Postgresql DB for Azure Django App

Tags: python, django, postgresql, azure

I was following the tutorial located here: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-azure-app-service/ and i made it all the way to opening up the SSH cli and typing the command "python manage.py migrate", but when i enter this i get the exception:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "mydbname port=5432" to address: Name or service not known
```

When i scroll up a little i read that this error was the direct result of the following exception:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "mydbname port=5432" to address: Name or service not known
```

I've checked my settings.py and my azure configs to make sure the info is correct. I'm at a complete loss, does anyone know what may be causing these exceptions to be thrown?
My application is deployed, I'm guessing I just can't connect to my postgresql database for some reason.

The suggested related question is concerning setting up a local postgresql, this is an issue with connecting to my postgresql database on Azure via the ssh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Unknown host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340726/could-not-translate-host-name-postgres-to-address-unknown-host)

Comment: This question is concerning setting up a local postgresql, this is an issue with connecting to my postgresql database on Azure via the ssh.

Comment: Hello @champlooSIXSIX In above answer first line says *"In order to use django with postgresql you need a reachable postgresql server."* Try to debug your postgres server check if it's available on given port and host, and your says that you've provided invalid host name *`error could not translate host name "mydbname"`*

Comment: So originally i had the port=5432 inside the DBHOST field, I tried making PORT its own parameter field, and now the error has changed. It's now stating 
"django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "appname-server.postgres.database.azure.com" (10.0.1.4), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "DBNAME" does not exist". This makes no sense though, I'm able to look on the Azure interface and see that the database DOES exist, and all the connection parameters are correct.

Comment: You're trying to access database **DBNAME**  that does not exists or not created becouse of that connection to your database is failed try to create db or use existing one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ankit Tiwari for pointing me in the right direction. The solution was to add -database to the end of my DBNAME field. So the field was DBNAME-database.

Comment: Hello @champlooSIXSIX you can improve your answer by adding an examples so it will be helpful for future readers.